# Using Case-When in Teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

Simple problem but driving me crazy for a while. Have following table in `Teradata`:

```
A       B
112211  
113311  56
226144  61
996688  66
005400  
771277
```

For the blank fields in `col-B` need to pull the numbers from `col-A` like:

```
SELECT A
CASE 'B'
WHEN 'B' IS NULL THEN SUBSTR('A',3,4)
END AS 'B'
FROM TABLE_T1;
```

Referred some documentation but not getting what's going wrong in the above query. This query will work on MySQL but why not in Teradata.

Expected O/P:

```
A       B
112211  22
113311  56
226144  61
996688  66
005400  54
771277  12
```

Comment: *why not in Teradata*: This will fail in most other DBMSes, too, because it's a mixture between *searched* `CASE WHEN condition THEN...`and *valued* `CASE column WHEN x THEN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this form of `case expression` note the difference is  `case when ...` not `case b when ...`. Also use single quotes for literals only, use double quotes for identities. (Note sure why you used single quotes.)

```
SELECT
      A
    , CASE WHEN B IS NULL THEN SUBSTR(A,3,4) 
           ELSE B 
      END AS "B"
FROM TABLE_T1;
```

But you can also use `coalesce()` for this I believe:

```
SELECT
      A
    , coalesce(B ,SUBSTR(A,3,4) AS "B"
FROM TABLE_T1;
```